# How to stub a method that returns void

Tags: objective-c, ocmockito

I hope my question is not too basic, as I am new to both obj-c and OCMockito!

I have a void method that I want to stub, so that it does not perform its actions when running a test.

My Method:

-(void)myVoidMethod
  { .. }

I would like to stub it in a way similar to this:

[given([mockDataManager saveChangesToCoreData])];

However if I dont specify a "willReturn" statement I get the following error:
**"Argument type 'void' is incomplete"**

How can I achieve this in OCMockito?

Comment: Can you explain you case more. Why do you want to stub void method?

Comment: I would like to prevent the insides (the functionality) of that specific method from running. The method I would like to stub, is called from within the method I am testing, but I would like to not execute the instructions inside it. Does that make sense?

Comment: In general I would avoid partial stubbing. It is good smell that design is not right.

Comment: You can find some solutions here: https://github.com/jonreid/OCMockito/issues/38

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After getting more details from comments I decide to write the answer here.

IMO partial stubbing (spies) are bad practise. I used it two times in really big legacy project and I would like to change that to something cleaner at some point.

The same opinion is shared between other people. As quick solution you could follow advice from [here](https://github.com/jonreid/OCMockito/issues/38) - subclass and override the method.

Answer (score 0):

Declaring dummy protocol where this method declared as returning id will fix compile error.

```
@protocol _dummyProtocol
    - (id)methodThatReallyReturnVoid;
@end

[[(id<_dummyProtocol>)[mockObject stub] methodThatReallyReturnVoid] andDo:^(NSInvocation *inv){}];
```